# Retrieve word just prior to a sigil / known value

Tags: bash

i have a text file with the following text. I want to retrieve the word just before `Infra` from each line:

```
        awesomebitchesz2.0  Infra  6     54 Mbit/s   79      ▂▄▆_  WPA2        
*       Bourbonhouse        Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  70      ▂▄▆_  WPA2        
        --                  Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  34      ▂▄__  WPA2 802.1X
```

the base of the file stays the same but the first names alwasy change i want to be able to pull the name of the certain AP. for instance i want to grep Bourbonhouse it will print out bourbonhose with now white spaces 
i figured to try and pull the first work before Infra as an indicator but all the solutions ive seen only pulls after the indicator. can someone either point me in the right direction or give me a demonstration.

Comment: Are you looking for a Python or a Bash script??? What have you tried so far?

Comment: thank you. but this i want to be able to pull a certain AP name

Comment: i want to get a bash solution first but finally i want to use it in a python application im building

Comment: If you're building a Python application, why use bash at all? Much more efficient to do all your logic in Python natively.

Comment: because the application im building is using bash scripts and is integrated with bash

Comment: The "why" question remains relevant. If you're "integrating with bash" in such a way that your call chain is bash->Python->bash->wifi-tools, that's *far* less efficient than just bash->Python->wifi-tools.

Comment: like i said before the application is already calling other bash commands. besides i want to make the code as long as possible. including making log files

Comment: since this question apparently got me banded from asking any more on this site how would i also remove color from the text. when i copy the CLI out put and paste it in a text file it copy's the color codes as well as unreadable special characters. how do i copy the test where it does not have these extra unreadable content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a shell-native regex to retrieve the word prior to `Infra` in each case might look like:

```
re='[[:space:]]([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+Infra'
while IFS= read -r line; do
  [[ $line =~ $re ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done
```

You can see this running with your input at https://ideone.com/TmVO5J

---

If your goal is to capture only the name with a `*` preceding, that might look like:

```
re='^[[:space:]]*[*][[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+Infra'
while IFS= read -r line; do
  [[ $line =~ $re ]] && { result="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; break; }
done

if [[ $result ]]; then
  echo "Found result: $result"
else
  echo "No result found"
fi
```

This version can be seen at https://ideone.com/VcoYM5

Comment: i like this format but what if i just want to get a fingle word. such as if i want to just get bourdon house or just get awesomebitchesz2.0? is there a way to grab just that one name?

Comment: Of course, you can break out of the loop any time you want to. `break` will do. That said, *how* do you want your script to know which of the various words to capture? If you don't know what logic you want it to follow, we can't tell you how to implement that logic.

Comment: so the way the app is suppose to work is there is a list box showing all available AP and if i click on one its suppose to connect to it. thats the short version of what it does

Comment: I again don't see why implementing any part of this program in bash would be a good idea. [`python-wifi`](https://pypi.org/project/python-wifi/), or [`python-networkmanager`](https://github.com/seveas/python-networkmanager) is going to have a lot less indirection.

Comment: because again im not just using network manager. there are multiple other tools and applications that i will be using in side mine. and theres not exactly a python method or class for those other apps.

Comment: So build a Python class for each possible backend.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no spaces in the AP names, you can use `cut` like this:

```
$ cat filename.txt | cut -c9- | cut -f1 -d ' '
awesomebitchesz2.0
Bourbonhouse
--
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using a `sed` regular expression might be your best bet here because it allows you to extract a specific group. This is what I came up with:

`sed -n 's/[\*\ ]*\(.*\) Infra.*$/\1/p'`

Here is the regex in action:

```
$ echo | sed -n 's/[\*\ ]*\(.*\) Infra.*$/\1/p' <<EOF
        awesomebitchesz2.0  Infra  6     54 Mbit/s   79      ▂▄▆_  WPA2
*       Bourbonhouse        Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  70      ▂▄▆_  WPA2
        --                  Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  34      ▂▄__  WPA2 802.1X
EOF
awesomebitchesz2.0
Bourbonhouse
--
```

As a bonus, this will handle cases where the AP name has spaces in it:

```
$ echo | sed -n 's/[\*\ ]*\(.*\) Infra.*$/\1/p' <<EOF
        awesomebitchesz2.0  Infra  6     54 Mbit/s   79      ▂▄▆_  WPA2
*       Bourbonhouse        Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  70      ▂▄▆_  WPA2
        Space  Wayzz        Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  34      ▂▄__  WPA2 802.1X
EOF

awesomebitchesz2.0
Bourbonhouse
Space  Wayzz
```